# How to import a jar file into eclipse as a project to use source code of classes of that jar

Tags: java

I have one jar file. I want to see the source code of classes of this jar file and i need to use source code of this jar file. Is there any option to view and use that jar file source code? 
Is there any option in eclipse to extract jar file and to see the source code of that jar file?

Answer (score 1):

if you add a jar as dependency to your project, you can also link sourcecode to it.
Rightclick on project->Build Path->Configure Buildpath. There, choose the jar that you linked into your project, extend it and under "source attachments", you can add the jar  that contains the sources of this specific jar

[image]

Comment: Actually you are saying the process to add jar file into buildpath. But i need to see the source code of all classes exists in that jar file. Is there any way to do in eclipse? Actually we have application tools to extract jar file but we can't see the source code of these classes. Is there any possibility to do this one in eclipse?

Comment: no, i described the process to add the source-code to a linked jar to be able to view the source of classes contained in the linked jar. Thats why i mentioned "SOURCE ATTACHMENTS". You need to have the source for that. If you DONT have the source-code, use a decompiler, e.g. a nice plugin for eclipse: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse

Comment: Sorry, i could not find "SOURCE ATTACHMENTS" after clicking "Configure Buildpath".

Comment: i added a picture. btw, i think, a decompiler is what you want, because you dont have the sourcecode...

Comment: Ok, you are describing the process to add some source code to linked jar file right? Actually i dont have source code of that jar file. Could please explain me how to add some code to linked jar file.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain me how to new code to existing linked jar? Actually i tried to add plug in for decompiler in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the JAR file with the byte code and attach the source JAR as well.  You can't do without the first; the second is optional.

It's easy to do in IntelliJ; I'm not sure about the steps in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The JAR file you are refering too may not have source code attached. 
Usually, when downloading third party library you can download JARs with byte-code and source code separetredly. The best way to check is to simply extract JAR file (with ZIP extracting tool) and check whether you have source there. If so, you can do the following:
 1. Add the JAR to your Eclipse project (just drag it there and choose whether you want to copy or link to the JAR).
 2. Whenever you are opening class file that does not come with source-code and you are shown "Source not found" page - just press button "Attach Source.." and find your JAR file with source code.

[EDIT] use [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)  to extract source code (*.java files) from *.class files contained in JAR file.

Comment: Thank, i dragged jar file into my project. It added in JRE System Library. I double clicked on that jar file but i can't open that jar file. Then how to see source code of classes[Presant in that jar file]?              Suppose, we have one.jar file and Two.class exists in that jar file then how to see the source code of that Two.class?

Comment: Ah, if you JAR does not contain separated *.java files for each *.class file you may try to use this JD-GUI - very simple app that let you extract source code from class file :) http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

Comment: Hey, if your questions is already answered (by me or other folks) please mark it as a solved and point the best answer so this questions could be closed and people would earn some reps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Your procjet. Chose properties.

Select Libraries
[image]
Chose Your jar
[image]
Profit
[image]

Comment: Actually you are saying the process to add jar file into buildpath. But i need to see the source code of all classes exists in that jar file. Is there any way to do in eclipse? Actually we have application tools to extract jar file but we can't see the source code of these classes. Is there any possibility to do this one in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had in Java Build Path Source attachment with meaningful path (not NONE), but file itself was absent in this place. I configure project to Maven nature. And then from Maven make Download sources - file -source.jar appears.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can see the source code of all the files those are added in your jar file.first you have to add jar file same as shown by the Marcin Szymczak. and after that click on "Referenced library". After that click on Your jar.and you can check all the classes source code.In my case jar file-Hackerrank.jar and you can see source code of classes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This applies to plugin jars (if that is your case):

1. Ensure to put the jar into your target platform folder
2. Refresh your target platform: Window -> Preferences -> Target Platform -> Select your current target -> Edit -> Finish -> Reload -> Ok
3. Open the "Plug-ins" view: Window -> Show view -> Plug-ins
4. In that view, locate the new plugin jar: right click and Import As -> Source Project.

You will have it as a plugin project in your workspace.